# capture a specific JSON-LD attribute with a regular expression in R

Tags: r, regex

Using R, I want to capture a specific attribute (`@type` in this case) out of a JSON-LD payload inside a `<script>` tag. Here's a sample fragment:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "WebSite",
        ...
```

This is a sample code in R to perform the attribute extraction:

```
x <- "<script type=\"application/ld+json\">{\"@context\":\"https://schema.org\",\"@type\":\"WebSite\",\"url\":\"https://www.foo.com/\""
regmatches(x, regexpr("<script [^>]*type *= *['\"] *application/ld.json *['\"][^>]*>[^}]+ ['\"] *@type *['\"] *: *['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"]", x, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

The output from this code is the following:

```
[1] "<script type=\"application/ld+json\">{    \"@context\": \"https://schema.org\"    \"@type\":\"WebSite\""
```

The output I expect is this one:

```
[1] "WebSite"
```

I don't have a solid experience with R and even less of a solid experience with regular expressions but what bugs me is I've already tried this regex in the [regex101 website](https://regex101.com) (you can check the test [here](https://regex101.com/r/8DkcnI/2)) and it works.

Can you give me a hint on how to return the correct attribute instead of the full test string?

Comment: `(?<=@type":\s)("\w*\")` try this regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use use a `\K` based PCRE pattern to extract any 1+ chars other than `'` and `"` after a specific pattern:

```
x <- "<script type=\"application/ld+json\">{\"@context\":\"https://schema.org\",\"@type\":\"WebSite\",\"url\":\"https://www.foo.com/\""
p <- "<script\\s[^>]*type *= *['\"] *application/ld.json *['\"][^>]*>[^}]+['\"] *@type *['\"] *: *['\"]\\K[^'\"]+"
regmatches(x, regexpr(p, x, ignore.case = TRUE, perl=TRUE))
## => "WebSite"
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/CHpHpJ)

It looks like `<SOME_LEFTHAND_CONTEXT_PATTERN>\K<WHAT_YOU_NEED>`. The `\K` operator will omit all text matched so far, and you will only get `<WHAT_YOU_NEED>` in the result.  See [this pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/3sTJgm/1). Do not forget `perl=TRUE` argument that will enable PCRE regex engine here.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! :)